# Transform properties not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to implement `navbar` such that on scrolling down, it will translate upwards and vice versa.

I am using React + gatsbyjs and styled-components for styling. 
I am also using react-animations for animating the navbar downwards after 8s.

```
import { fadeInDown } from react-animation;
const fadeInAnimation = keyframes`${fadeInDown}`;
```

Below is the CSS for the navbar:

```
const FadeInDiv = styled.nav`
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    font-size: 1em;
    transform: translateY(-100px);
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-delay: 8s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-name: ${fadeInAnimation};

    @media (min-width: 1400px) {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
`;
```

After which, I used chrome dev-tool to change the style of navbar, trying to implement it using transform.

```
transform: translateY(-20px);
```

However, it doesn't affect the nav at all. Is there any reason why?

Comment: You picked the exact element? try `transform: translateY(-20px) !important;`.

Comment: @ColinCline yup i selected nav element and added the `transform: translateY(-20px)` to the style. Just tried it with `!important`, still no changes. `top: -20px` works though

Comment: could you provide a codepen or jsfidde ?

Comment: tried to use -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px); transform: translateY(-20px);